# MAX Value empty in doctrine query result

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following issue when using a createQuery() in combination with the MAX function in Doctrine.

The entry in the result array where the maximum value should be (and is in normal SQL) is empty.

Maybe this is caused by the use of DATE_DIFF inside MAX?

```
$em->createQuery('SELECT d.action, d.environmentId,MAX(DATE_DIFF(d.timeStart,d.timeDone)) AS max_value FROM DBMAINTANANCE as d GROUP BY d.environmentId,d.action');
```

The result array is:

```
Array ( [action] => copy [environmentId] => 5 [max_value] => )
```

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

(Using Zend Framework 2 with the DoctrineORMModule)

Comment: wild guess change DATE_DIFF to DATEDIFF

Comment: In addition to @dixromos98 I would think about the order of the DATEDIFF parameters. If the attribute names don't lie the result would be a negative date

Comment: Unfortunately DATE_DIFF is Doctrine Query Language. Not normal SQL.
(http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions) I will try to switch those variables ;)

Comment: Just tried switching the parameters, unfortunately it had no effect..